# What does 'GET OR SET ACCESSOR EXPECTED' mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class RepeaterEx2 : System.Web.UI.Page {
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    DataSet ds = null;
    String strSqlQuery = String.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Server=(local);Data base=TestDb;Uid=sa;Password=123";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }

    }
    void BindEmpData
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter( "select e.ENO,e.ENAME,e.JOB,e.SAL,d.DNAME form EMPLOYEE e,DEPARTMENT d where e.DNO=d.DNO",cn);

        da.Fill(ds,"EMPLOYEE");//here showing set or get accessorexpected error at "da"
        Repeater1.DataSource=ds.Table["EMPLOYEE"];
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> A get or set accessor expected

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need parentheses after the function name here:

```
void BindEmpData()
{
    ...
}
```

Also, you'll want to make sure you initialize the `DataSet` correctly:

```
void BindEmpData()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select e.ENO,e.ENAME,e.JOB,e.SAL,d.DNAME form EMPLOYEE e,DEPARTMENT d where e.DNO=d.DNO",cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds,"EMPLOYEE"); 
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Table["EMPLOYEE"];
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

And at this point you can remove the `ds` and `da` class members, since they are no longer being used (they've been replaced by function variables).

Answer (score 5):

Parentheses is required to differentiate a method from a property that requires the [get/set syntax](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property)