# Error in data binding in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

```
I have tried data binding in WPF.
But it is showing few errors.Please help me.
```

I am attaching the code.I have create a simple text block and tried to bind the string. Also I want to know how Windows.datacontext works? In my code it is giving an error. please help me out.

```
Xaml code
<Window x:Class="Shweta.DataBinding"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataBinding" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <l:DataBinding />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="224*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="59*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="202*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding TextString, TargetNullValue=Test}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

**Code behind**

namespace Shweta
{
    public partial class DataBinding : Window
    {
        public DataBinding()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Setupviewmodel();
        }
        private void Setupviewmodel
        {
            TextString="this worked";
        }
        public string TextString{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: "few errors"? *What* errors?

Comment: Error 1 A get or set accessor expected
Error 2 ''l' is an undeclared prefix. Line 6, position 10.' XML is not valid.
Error 3 The name 'Setupviewmodel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Typo: you are missing `()` after `Setupviewmodel`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20804558/993547.

Comment: Thanks. () is added. the second error is not getting resolved.Error 2 ''l' is an undeclared prefix. Line 6, position 10.' XML is not valid.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, at least not of the thread you posted @PatrickHofman. Problem is the namespace `l` is not defined in xaml + you are using codebehind of a xaml as viewmodel, you should create another class for that.

Comment: @user yes. It was of revision 1 of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first of all read the error messages ... It clearly says that `l` is not defined in `XAML` but still you're trying to use it : `<l:DataBinding />`...

Fix this by declaring `l` in your `XAML` :

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.DataBinding"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:l="<your l declaration"/>
```

Another thing is that you haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you'r value wont get updated anyway.

Implement this like such :

```
public partial class DataBinding : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    string text;
    public string TextString
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public DataBinding()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Setupviewmodel();
        // as @Nahuel Ianni stated, he has to set DataContext to CodeBehind
        // in order to be able to get bindings work 
        DataContext = this; // <-- only if not binded before
    }

    public void Setupviewmodel() // forgot to to place () 
    // produced error : `A get or set accessor expected`
    {
        TextString = "this worked";
    }
}
```

Yet another thing is that you have to specify `DataContext` only when it's not the same as your code behind so you do not need this part :

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <l:DataBinding />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not specifying the `DataContext` correctly as you are trying to set it up on XAML by using a namespace that has not been declared. For more info on XAML namespaces, check the [following link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your example it would be on the xaml side:

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.DataBinding"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataBinding" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="224*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="59*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="202*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding TextString, TargetNullValue=Test}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in your code behind:

```
namespace Shweta
{
    public partial class DataBinding : Window
    {
        public DataBinding()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;  // Pay attention to this line!
            Setupviewmodel();
        }

        private void Setupviewmodel()
        {
            TextString="this worked";
        }

        public string TextString{get;set;}
    }
}
```

The difference with the original version is that I'm not specifying the `DataContext` on XAML but on the code behind itself.

The `DataContext` can be considered as the place where the view will retrieve the information from. When in doubt, please refer to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) or you could learn about the [MVVM pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) which is the pillar of working with XAML.

Comment: You only need to change `DataContext` if it not the same object as `CodeBehind`. Additionaly you haven't used `INotifyPropertyChanged` so value of the `TextBlock` wont update.

Comment: @m.rogalski The interface comment is correct although not part of the problem the user is stating, but the DataContext is needed to be set to itself (or some other object) otherwise it will not work properly. In the code I proposed, the binding will work even if only for the first time.

Comment: I didn't had to set `DataContext` to anything and it worked. I think this might depend on the framework itself. This may be reasonable

Comment: @m.rogalski Can't argue there. In my local project, when I tried it; without the this statement there was no binding at all.

Comment: That's something worth knowing. Thanks for the tip. Now I'll know that sometimes this might cause the problems with bindings :)

Comment: `this.DataContext = this` is an extreme anti-pattern! Don't do this!

Answer (score -2):

In order to make this work you have to set the `DataContext` properly. I'd suggest to create a viewmodel class and bind to that. Also I initialized the binding in the codebehind because your namespaces are missing. You can do that in xaml aswell. For now to give you something to work with try this for your codebehind:

```
public partial class DataBinding : Window
{
  public DataBinding()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new DataBindingViewModel();
  }
}

public class DataBindingViewModel
{
  public DataBindingViewModel()
  {
    Setupviewmodel();
  }
  private void Setupviewmodel()
  {
    TextString = "this worked";
  }
  public string TextString { get; set; }
}
```

And change your view to this:

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.DataBinding"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataBinding" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="224*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="59*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="202*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding TextString, TargetNullValue=Test}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that the `Text` property will only be set at initialization. If you want DataBinding at runtime your `DataBindingViewModel` will have to implememnt `INPC` and throw the `PropertyChanged` Event after setting the property bound to.

Comment: Creating a new class as a ViewModel is not necessary for bindings in XAML, he can use the code behind for binding values without a problem.

Comment: @NahuelIanni You can also have a billion classes in one .cs file or write all your code in one line.

Comment: Indeed you can, but you are mixing problems there. The lack of an extra class is not the cause of the problem he is having; it's just a different pattern (or lack of). The issue resides somewhere else.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Ofc this is not the problem, why the programm wont run. Thats why I adressed the DataContext problem aswell.